# Better way to map multiple values (inject)

Tags: ruby, collections

Please suggest a better (Ruby-ish) way to summarise mutiple entries in one go given the code below:

```
def summary_totals
  pay_paid, pay_unpaid = 0, 0
  rec_paid, rec_unpaid = 0, 0
  net_paid, net_unpaid = 0, 0

  summary_entries.each do |proj_summary|
    pay_paid   += proj_summary.payable.paid || 0
    pay_unpaid += proj_summary.payable.unpaid || 0
    rec_paid   += proj_summary.receivable.paid || 0
    rec_unpaid += proj_summary.receivable.unpaid || 0
    net_paid   += proj_summary.net.paid || 0
    net_unpaid += proj_summary.net.unpaid || 0
  end

  pay = PaidUnpaidEntry.new(pay_paid, pay_unpaid)
  rec = PaidUnpaidEntry.new(rec_paid, rec_unpaid)
  net = PaidUnpaidEntry.new(net_paid, net_unpaid)
  ProjectPaymentsSummary.new(pay, rec, net)
end
```

**Update:** All you need to do is to rewrite the `each` loop (which sums up 6 variables) in a better Ruby style.

Comment: Do you have a sample data, expected output?

Comment: @JeffPrice what for? The code is self explanatory.

Comment: This question belongs in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

"Better" could be subjective, but I guess you want to use inject to do the summing.  The symbol argument to inject can be used to make it nice and concise.  If you pass the result directly to your constructors, there's no need for the local variables, eg:

```
pay = PaidUnpaidEntry.new(
  summary_entries.map { |e| e.payable.paid   }.inject(:+),
  summary_entries.map { |e| e.payable.unpaid }.inject(:+)
)
# etc
```

Comment: The key thing was "in one go". This way I'll have to do 6 iterations over the same collection instead of just one (current ugly impl.).